# Optimize find and combine in list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list which can contains hundreds of thousands of lists where int are stored. Let's say for example:

```
list = [ [0,5,9], [1,2,4], [1,2,7,4], [3,100,42] ... ]
```

I need to create a new list that contains all the elements where a specific element is present.
For example my `new_list[0]` will be a flat list of all list where element 0 exists.

A dumb for-for loops would be like:

```
# list_ref <- my list of list
gr_cl=[]
for i in range(len(list_ref)):
    clust=[]
    for j in list_ref:
        if i in j:
            clust.append(j)
    gr_cl.append([item for sublist in clust for item in sublist]) #flat it

# set
gr_cl_set = [list(set(item)) for item in gr_cl]
```

I tried to implement it as list comprehension, but it still takes too much time to make my code efficient.

Any idea?

Comment: A constraint to limit the output list is missing in the question, unless you do want as a response to you example a list of a least 101 (max of elements) items. Try to give a complete example.

could you give amore complete  example  where some sub list are not keept

Comment: Your algorithm if O(n²) x O(append()) x ... For large list of "hundreds of thousands" sublists, it is not efficient. List comprehension will not improve timings by much. You should find another algorithm, may be following @James Welch suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, but the question miss a contraint to limit the output list is missing.

The code below give all sublist to the maximum of the from collections import defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

inputlist= [ [0,5,9], [1,2,4], [1,2,7,4], [3,100,42]  ]

# create a dictionary in which :
#  keys : value of the elements of the sublists
#  values : index of the sublists of inputlist which contains the key
elt_refs = defaultdict(list)
max_value = 0
for i, sublist in enumerate(inputlist):
    for elt in sublist:
        if elt > max_value: max_value = elt
        elt_refs[elt].append(i)

# build the result by iterating on the list of the element of the dictionnary
# and filling the gaps 
result = []
result_i = 0
for k, refs in sorted(elt_refs.items()):
    # fill the gaps
    gap = k - result_i - 1
    for _ in range(gap):
        result.append([])

    result_i = k

    # flatten refs
    flat = []
    for ref in refs:
        flat.extend(inputlist[ref])

    result.append(list(set(flat)))

print(result)
```

Comment: Wow thanks works perfectly on a great time !